# Chrome extension loop through array during page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a page which reloads every time a button is clicked so the script stops. However I need the script to loop through an array even after the page reloads. Should I run my script directly in the background.js file instead of executing another script? If so, not sure how. I originally tried a Chrome App with webview but couldn't find a way to click the button.

```
<div id="button">click here</div>
```

//manifest

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "CycleThru",
"version": "1.0",
"offline_enabled": true,
"icons": { "16": "on.png",
           "48": "on.png",
          "128": "on.png" },
 "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
   "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
"content_scripts": [
{
"matches": ["<all_urls>"],
"css": ["on.css"],
"js": ["jquery.min.js"]
} ],
 "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "off.png"
  }
}
```

//background JS

```
var toggle = false;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  toggle = !toggle;
  if(toggle){
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "on.png", tabId:tab.id});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"on.js"});
  }
  else{
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png", tabId:tab.id});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"off.js"});
  }
});
```

//script that needs to keep running

```
var candy = ["twix", "taffy"];
for(var i = 0; i < candy.length; i++) {
  $("#button").click();
  setTimeout(function(){ console.log("candy") }, 3000);
}
```

I have the setTimout to give the page time to finish reloading before going to the next array time.

Comment: what is `SetTimeout`? is that some wrapper over `setTimeout`?

Comment: note: if that was meant to be `setTimeout` it does not *pause* the loop, if that's what you think would happen ... you'd end up with `candy` logged to the console *twice* after 3 seconds

Comment: It was a typo. I had setTimeout to pause before continuing to the next itme.

Comment: as I said, if it was meant to be `setTimeout` that won't do what you think - setTimeout is *asynchronous*, so will not "pause" javascript for you

Answer (score 0):

you can send a message from the content script to the background script to do the calculations. maybe hold a cooldown in the background script as well to combat spamming. then you can send the results if needed back to the content script using messages.

check this out: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: I'm thinking this is the way to go. Thanks!